# cannot create SubscribableChannel in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

This works in Java:

```
SubscribableChannel c = MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
```

converted to kotlin (by IntelliJ) this becomes:

```
val c : SubscribableChannel = MessageChannels.publishSubscribe<S>().get()
```

I cannot find a Type that can satisfy the requirements for "S"

The signature or publishSubscribe is:

```
public static <S extends PublishSubscribeChannelSpec<S>> PublishSubscribeChannelSpec<S> publishSubscribe()
```

what can satisfy `<S extends PublishSubscribeChannelSpec<S>>` when `S` recursively depends on `S`?

And why isn't this a problem for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
val c: SubscribableChannel = MessageChannels.publishSubscribe<PublishSubscribeSpec>().get()
```

Why it works without the type in Java I have no idea. My guess would be that Java is able to infer the type, but I don't know why Kotlin can't do the same.

Comment: yes, this is compile clean - however i found out that FluxMessageChannel fits my needs better - thanks anyway :)